# How to count the number of times a value appears in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I've been tasked with creating a "pown-chess" game, and i'm trying to figure out how to code the win condition. Is there any way to have python count the number of times a given value appears in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a list of the dict's values, and use its `count` method.

```
result = list(mydict.values()).count(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for a beginner (like me) is to apply Counter from collections to the values of your dictionary:

```py
from collections import Counter
d=dict([(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,1),(6,3),(7,2),(8,3)])
# d:(key,val) --> dd:(val,freq_of_val_in_d) 
dd=Counter(d.values())
print(dd)
```

gives:

```
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2})
```